# Hibernate domain object 'not null' field - mock test should throw error if field is null within object

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, junit, powermockito

There is an Hibernate domain object that have 'not null' field which have annotation `@Column(nullable=false)`, a DAO class method which is saving this object in DB.

I am mocking the create DAO call using `PowerMockito`, mock call is working fine but if i am passing null for the field, mock test is not throwing error that field is null.

Below is the code, tools/techs (java, spring, hibernate, sqlserver, junits, powermockit). Few code changes omitted related to spring context and hibernate session configurations.

```
public class Entity{
    private String id;
    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String field;
    //setters and getters goes here
}

public class HibernateDAO{
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void create(Entity entity){
        getSession().save(entity);
    }

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sf){
        sessionFactory = sf;
    }
}

public class HibernateDAOTest{
    HibernateDAO hibernateDAO = new HibernateDAO();
    public SessionFactory mockedSessionFactory; 
    public Session mockedSession; 
    public Query query;
    public SQLQuery sqlQuery;
    public Transaction mockedTransaction;
    @Before
    public void setup() {
        mockedSessionFactory =  PowerMockito.mock(SessionFactory.class);
        mockedSession = PowerMockito.mock(Session.class);
        mockedTransaction = PowerMockito.mock(Transaction.class);
        query = PowerMockito.mock(Query.class);
        sqlQuery = PowerMockito.mock(SQLQuery.class);

        PowerMockito.when(mockedSessionFactory.openSession()).thenReturn(mockedSession);
        PowerMockito.when(mockedSessionFactory.getCurrentSession()).thenReturn(mockedSession);
        PowerMockito.when(mockedSession.beginTransaction()).thenReturn(mockedTransaction);
    }

    @Test
    public void testCreate(){
        Entity entityToSave = new Entity();
        entityToSave.setId("123");
        entityToSave.setField(null);
        hibernateDAO.setSessionFactory(mockedSessionFactory);
        hibernateDAO.create(entityToSave);//this call should throw error that "field" is null but its not.          
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Actually the validation (not-nullability check) is not done in your DAO.** You do declare your field as not-null, but then your `create(Entity entity)` method calls:

```
    getSession().save(entity);
```

and that is all it does. Now the validation would happen within the saving via `HibernateSession`, but all those classed are mocked. So they will not perform any validation.

Generally it is a good rule, that each time you accidentally mock the very same thing you tested, you step back and re-evaluate:

> Did I write that code? Why do I want to test it?

In this case probably the answer is, that you should trust Hibernate taking care of things. And if you want to test your model definition, you need to setup a full Hibernate context and perform a real test with Hibernate not being mocked.